# Detecting/Debugging/Viewing Tiff/BigTiff files which are probably broken

Tags: debugging, image-processing, editor, tiff, libtiff

I have received a BigTiff file with scientific data which can't be read properly with ImageJ/Fiji. There seems to be a problem with LibTiff and the StripOffsets tag.

The only options I found are using LibTiff directly (probably bad, if I'm not sure if the issue is caused by LibTiff itself) and ImageJ/Fiji.

Is there a way to have a "higher level" access (i. e. no hex editor) on the provided data?
E. g. some library or tool to "debug" the file and change properties on the fly?

Comment: If you need another set of eyes to look at the problem, I'll be happy to take a look at the TIFF file and see what I find. Please email a link to the file and see if my code can successfully read it.

Comment: Yes, that would be very nice! Where do I find your email address?

Comment: It's in my profile too (bitbank@pobox.com)

Comment: Ouch. I'm sorry, I was completely drowning in work and forgot it. Thanks for all your endurance. It seems that the creator of the scientific data has changed or updated his library and from what I have heard it works, but I have been unable to get an example file until now. I'll respond back if I got my hands on it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and in my case when the files were too big for the viewers they sent this message of problems with the StripOffsets tag. Now I use my [IIPImage](http://iipimage.sourceforge.net/) viewer, that I builded with libtiff 4.0.3 (with BigTIFF support), to view my file, but I still am in search for a good viewer for huge TIFF files.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: Of course it is, I am saying that it is the viewer that can't load big images